# How to convert data into normal distribution

Tags: python, logic, normalization, transformation, data-science

I have a data set consists of number of page views in 6 months for 30k customers. It also consists of following:

- Number of unique OS used
- Number of unique Browsers user
- Number of unique cookies used
  All these numbers are taken over a period of six months.

Now I did try to do a normal test using:

```
from scipy.stats import normaltest
k2, p = normaltest(df)
print(p)
```

Which returns 0.0 meaning the data is not following normal distribution.

Now I want to know why is that? I thought that generally as the size increases, we see normal distribution in data, since the data has a size of 30k I was not able to understand why it was not normally distributed.

I did try converting them into Z score, but still no luck. Can I transform my data such that I can have a normal distribution? Is there any method using which I can do that?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). You can't change the distribution of your data- it is what it is. If you have a set of IID random variables, the sum tends towards a normal distribution. The classic example is rolling N dice and summing their results.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to plot your data, first of all histograms. I think you will see what is wrong with your data. Also provide few example rows from your df.

Comment: "I thought that generally as the size increases, we see normal distribution in data"

As far as I understand, this isn't quite what the Central Limit Theorem says. Rather, it says that if you have enough samples, then the distribution of *sample averages* becomes normal.

Answer (score 1):

In the area I work in we typically Log transform data which is heteroscedastic like yours probably is. In my area (mass spectrometry), small values are far more likely than large, so we end up with an exponential distribution.

I'm guessing your data will look like mine, in which case you will need to do a log transform of your data to make it normally distributed. I would do this so that I can apply t-tests and other stats models.

Something like

```
df_visits = df_visits.apply(lambda x: np.log(x))
```

of course you will also need to get rid of any zeros before you can log transform.

[Image showing pre Vs post log transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA0m4.png)

Comment: More generally, the OP might also be interested in the Box-Cox transform, which equals the log transform for lambda equal to zero https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation